# Android - Linear Layout arrangement, not positioning as expected

Tags: android, layout

The following is my code. I want an interface where I have a single line textbox, a multiline textbox with 2 buttons below. I want the multiline textbox to occupy all the  space available after rendering the buttons and textbox. For this I created two LinearLayouts inside the main layout. The first one has vertical orientation with layout_width set to fill_parent. The second one is horizontal with fill_parent again.

The first one has a textbox for which I have set the layout_height to fill parent. The second one has two textboxes OK and Cancel.

When I run this application I get the UI, but the Buttons are very small (about 5px in height). I have to set the button height manually. What am I doing wrong here. I don't want to hard code the button height.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Contents"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="top"  />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button android:id="@+id/okbutt" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="OK" android:layout_weight="1"  />
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious how to do this, so I decided to try it out. This was what I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/buttons"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/okbutt" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="OK" />
    <Button 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Cancel" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textview1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:text="Name" />
  <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/textedit1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/textview1" />
  <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textview2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_below="@id/textedit1"
     android:text="Contents" />
  <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/textedit2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_below="@id/textview2" 
     android:layout_above="@id/buttons" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks svdree, your solution works. Still wondering why mine did not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative layout here instead of two linear layouts,i think it will give more clear ui.  and
if u want to increase height of button manually just increase the height of text written on button, i.e. height of OK and cancel with

> android:textSize

try this, may be this one helps you.